# Perl Regex not working in Bash script?

Tags: regex, bash

I have a regular expression:

```
^(.+?)(\.[^.]+$|$)
```

which separates a file name and the file extension (if there is one)
http://movingtofreedom.org/2008/04/01/regex-match-filename-base-and-extension/

Works perfectly fine in Perl

Say $FILE ='.myfile.form.txt'

$1 is '.myfile.form' and

$2 is '.txt', as they should be

I know Bash regex and Perl regex aren't the same, but I've never had a problem with Bash Rematching until now

But when I try to use in in a Bash script as, say...

```
FILE='.myfile.form.txt'
[[ $FILE =~ ^(.+?)(\.[^.]+$|$) ]]
```

${BASH_REMATCH[1]} will just have the entire file name (.myfile.form.txt), and nothing in ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}

I'm wondering what's wrong/going on here

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What makes you think bash and Perl accept the same regular expressions?  They are different programs with different rules.

Comment: In a bash script if you want to match, you could use grep, with -P, for using Perl expressions. (more info: $grep --help )

Comment: O sorry, I didn't clarify. I know they're not the same, I'm wondering what I could change so it will work as intended in a Bash script. And I did try 'grep -oP', but the system I need this to run on doesn't allow the -P flag, installed grep without it. Plus the rematching in grep won't save the group matching. And even with -o, a file name will be printed as one line, not separated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`regex(7)` which is referenced by `regex(3)` which is referenced by `bash(1)` makes no mention of greediness modifiers. Your pattern cannot be implemented in bash regex.

This doesn't mean you can't achieve what you want, though.

```
[[ $FILE =~ ^(.+)(\.[^.]*)$ ]] || [[ $FILE =~ ^(.*)()$ ]]
file="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
ext="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
```

Or something more straightforward like

```
if [[ $FILE =~ ^(.+)(\.[^.]*)$ ]]; then
   file="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
   ext="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
else
   file="$FILE"
   ext=""
fi
```